# Enzyme double dive into component inside Provider

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I've got a component that is accessing Redux store. I wrap it in Provider like this:

```
player = shallow(<Provider store={store}><MusicPlayer/></Provider>).dive();
```

when I run player.debug() it's displaying:

```
<MusicPlayer/>
```

As I can understand, current dive is displaying contents of Provider. Since I need to access my MusicPlayer component, I add an extra dive:

```
player = shallow(<Provider store={store}><MusicPlayer/></Provider>).dive().dive();
```

and I get this error:

> Invariant Violation: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a Provider

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If this is testing using enzyme, use mount instead of shallow for class components